# Como dividir código em vários módulos?

Tags: node.js

Eu sei que é possível separar funções em outros arquivos no Node, chamados módulos, da seguinte maneira:

***servidor.js***

```
var http = require("http");
var servidor = http.createServer();
var porta = 3000;

var corpo = require("./modulo-corpo.js");

servidor.on("request", function (request, response) {
    var resposta = corpo.getCorpo();
    response.writeHead(200, {
        "Content-Type": "text/plain",
        "Content-Length": resposta.length
    });
    response.end(resposta);
});

servidor.listen(porta, function () {
    console.log("servidor da bete, rodando na porta " + porta);
});
```

***modulo-corpo.js***

```
var n = 0;
exports.getCorpo = function() {
    return "bete beijou " + ++n + " bebados barrigudos bebendo bebidas baratas";
}
```

> Gostaria de saber quais os recursos disponíveis para organização do código no Node.

*Um exemplo prático do que eu imagino seria acessar a variável `n` do módulo corpo, como se ela tivesse sido declarada no arquivo `servidor.js`.*

> O intuito é organizar o código, fazendo, por exemplo, um módulo só com variáveis, outro só com rotas, etc., para que ele seja mais fácil de ser tratado/alterado/expandido no futuro.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Da maneira como está o `n` é inacessível a outros módulos e `n` comporta-se como *variavel privada* do módulo. Isso é muito útil em muitos casos.

Se quiseres consultar o `n` tens de fazer um `getter` que poderia ser assim:

```js
var n = 0;
exports.getCorpo = function() {
  return "bete beijou " + (++n) + " bêbados barrigudos bebendo bebidas baratas";
}
Object.defineProperty(exports, 'n', {
  get: function() {
    return n;
  }
});
```

Assim o módulo fica com uma propriedade `n` que vai buscar o valor real de `n` sem poder ser sobrescrito.

Se quiseres manipular o `n` podes fazer um setter também:

```
Object.defineProperty(exports, 'n', {
  get: function() {
    return n;
  },
  set: function(valor) {
    n = valor;
  }
});
```

---

Fiz um exemplo online que podes fazer download e testar ([link](https://preview.c9users.io/sergiocrisostomo/ptso-202891/)). A ideia é:

ficheiro: server.js

```
const http = require('http');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const variaveis = require("./variaveis");
const rotas = require("./rotas")(app);

const server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function(){
    const host = server.address().address;
    const port = server.address().port;
    console.log('App listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

ficheiro: variaveis.js

```
let contador = 0;

const variaveis = Object.create(Object.prototype, {
  carregamento: { // data em que o servidor comeÃ§ou a correr
    writable: false,
    configurable: false,
    value: new Date() 
  },
  contador: {
    configurable: false,
    get: function() { return contador++ },
    set: function(valor) {
      contador = valor;
    }
  }
});

module.exports = variaveis;
```

ficheiro: rotas.js

```
const variaveis = require("./variaveis");
module.exports = (app) => {
    app.use('/', (req, res) => {
       res.end('O contador esta em: ' + variaveis.contador); 
    });

    app.use(function(req, res, next){
        console.log(req.originalUrl);
    });
}
```

Com esta estrutura é possivel a qualquer ficheiro saber o valor de `contador` assim como mudar o seu valor de fora do ficheiro onde essa variável está inserida.