# Como Interromper setInterval no JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, setinterval

como faço para interromper a execução de um `setInterval` que está sendo executado em um módulo que não preciso mais? Não estou falando de apenas pegar o retorno do `setInterval` e executar um `clearInterval`. Não é isso...

Exemplo:

**app.js**

```
// Rota de data e hora para uma página que exibe em tempo real essa informações para o usuário
const dateTimeSystem  = require('./routes/date-time');
// outros códigos
app.use('/datetime' , dateTimeSystem);
```

**date-time.js**

```
// meus códigos...
//...
//..

setInterval(atualizaDataHora, 1000);

function atualizaDataHora() {
    // meus outros códigos...
}
```

Quando eu acesso a rota para a página de data hora, essa atualização contínua está correta e pode ficar indefinidamente enquanto eu estiver na página. Porém, ao ir para qualquer outra rota/página, preciso que essa função "atualizaDataHora" deixe de ser executada de um em um segundo, pois já não preciso mais dela. Verifiquei em modo debug que ela continua a ser executada mesmo depois de eu mudar para outra página.

Como faço para interromper o `setInterval` neste caso?

Answer (score 1):

> *"Não estou falando de apenas pegar o retorno do setInterval e executar um clearInterval. Não é isso..."*

Acho que é exatamente isso. O "retorno" do setInterval é um ponteiro para poderes chamar o `clearInterval` que o cancela. Essa é a unica maneira de parar o setInterval.

Outra maneira que podes usar, mas que não pára, é teres uma flag na função que dê return cedo caso já não seja necessária, mas para parar mesmo só com:

const ponteiro = setInterval(atualizaDataHora, 1000);

```
function atualizaDataHora() {
    // meus outros códigos...

    // e quando já não for mais preciso:
    clearInterval(ponteiro);
}
```

Comment: Sim, eu concordo que é o `clearInterval` que tem a tarefa de interromper a execução da rotina temporizada com o `setInterval`. O que não estou conseguindo entender é: uma vez armazenado o ponteiro de retorno do `setInterval` ainda dentro do arquivo `date-time.js`, ao mudar para outra rota/página (qualquer rota...) eu "pego" esse ponteiro de que maneira para interromper o `setInterval`?

Comment: @wBB nesse caso o ficheiro `date-time.js` tem de exportar o ponteiro, ou uma função com ele no escopo. E no router tens de ligar e desligar isso. Uma pergunta, esse `setInterval` corre código assíncrono demorado?

Comment: desculpe a pergunta de iniciante, aliás, por ser iniciante estou confuso em relação a muitas coisas em Nodejs, mas numa linguagem "tradicional" eu criaria uma variável Global, por exemplo, a qual poderia ser acessada de qualquer lugar. Eu não entendo como isso funciona no Nodejs... Sobre sua pergunta, do código assíncrono demorado, você quer saber se é um código extenso e por esse motivo é demorado para ser executado? Se sua pergunta for sobre isso, a resposta é não, ou seja, o código não é longo, portanto é de rápida execução.

Comment: @wBB pergunta de iniciante não precisa desculpa, é para isso que o site existe :) O Node não tem globais, cada arquivo é um módulo. Podes ver [esta pergunt/resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/202891/129) sobre isso. Em relação ao código ser demorado, a ideia seria: uma vêz que não é demorado, não podes correr esse código `atualizaDataHora ` com o pedido o cliente pendente e depois dele correr então dar a resposta ao pedido `res.send(...`?

Comment: Obrigado Sérgio. Gostei da opção usando Getters e Setters da sua resposta ao outro tópico. Acho que dessa maneira vai dar certo. Sobre sua outra solução, dando resposta ao pedido do `res.send` após percorrer o código de `atualizaDataHora`, verificando meu código não consegui identificar como implementar dessa forma. Tenho uma integração como `socket.io`, que por sua vez está integrado com outras coisas, enfim... está tão confuso quanto pode ser aos olhos de que está começando a se familiarizar com isso. Mas obrigado novamente pela ajuda!

Comment: Num teste preliminar funcionou muito bem essa sua opção indicada no outro tópico. Só estou achando estranho que ao fazer o teste com os códigos que você sugeriu, quando carrego no browser são executadas duas requisições, Consequentemente, em lugar do contador "global" incrementar de apenas 1 ao total, são incrementados 2 a cada requisição (que é executada em duplicidade). Fiz um comentário lá....